# "I can use computers, grandson!"

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

My grandmother loves matchstick puzzles. Every time I visit, she shows me a brand new set for me to solve. I visited her recently for her birthday, and I was excited to receive a puzzle in exchange for my gifts. I opened the envelope and three sheets of paper fell out.

## 1

> [image: Puzzle]

## 2

> [image: Puzzle]

## 3

> ```
> LSSIEHHNOHOFLSHNNNOFNHIIELET
> ```

---

I did not understand, so I asked my grandmother for clarification.

> "Grandma? What does this mean?"
>
> "I learned how to use the computer! See, even the matchsticks look digital!"
>
> "Come on, that's called pixel art. So what's the puzzle?"
>
> "What's my favourite show?"
>
> "Huh?"
>
> "Look at where the tips of the matchsticks land!"
>
> "Grandma, do you need a doctor?"
>
> "No, why?"

I left her alone after that, but these pixel matchsticks look intimidating...

---

Hint 1:

> Notice how [matches](/questions/tagged/matches) is not a tag.

Hint 2:

> Only what is in the blockquotes is important.

Hint 3:

> The colour and direction of the matchsticks do not matter.

Comment: two of the blue colors are really close to each other, is there any way to make them more distingushable? I have a hard time see which is which xD

Comment: @LioraHaydont They look pretty different to me, maybe adjust your monitor settings?

Comment: I mean like blue and indigo, I tried on 3 different screens. The issue is not when they are next to each others, but in the 2nd "paper" they are far from each other sometimes so I never know which of the 2 is here

Comment: @LioraHaydont I can see that now. Sorry about that, jafe's answer has all the coordinates, so you can use that as a reference.

Comment: @Zimonze I don't think the yellow-orange match should be there. It should end in rot13:-rf not in -rgf

Comment: Yes, that match should not be there, something got messed up in the process. The answer ends in rot13(rf).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Line up clues 2 and 3, and we have 28 colour pairs corresponding to 28 letters.
>  
>  - (orange, magenta) = L
>  - (red, indigo) = S
>  - (cyan, magenta) = S
>  - (dark green, indigo) = I
>  - (indigo, indigo) = E
>  - (magenta, blue) = H
>  - (orange, indigo) = H
>  - (blue, magenta) = N
>  - (blue, indigo) = O
>  - (indigo, light green) = H
>  - (orange, red) = O
>  - (yellow, light green) = F
>  - (light green, orange) = L
>  - (light green, yellow) = S
>  - (red, red) = H
>  - (magenta, red) = N
>  - (orange, dark green) = N
>  - (dark green, orange) = N
>  - (dark green, blue) = O
>  - (magenta, dark green) = F
>  - (cyan, blue) = N
>  - (dark green, cyan) = H
>  - (yellow, blue) = I
>  - (cyan, dark green) = I
>  - (yellow, cyan) = E
>  - (blue, blue) = L
>  - (red, blue) = E
>  - (yellow, orange) = T
>  
>  Since the first image has colours in its X and Y axis, we can use the colour pairs as coordinates and insert the letters into the image in their correct place.
>  
>  [image]
>  @PL457 figured out that this is a sudoku puzzle. Solving for all letters:
>  [image]

So the final answer:

> Picking all the letters which are in the same square as a matchstick tip produces THE FLINTSTONETS (extra T there?)

Comment: Have you tried its inverse, like (magenta, orange) instead of (orange, magenta)?

Comment: Yeah, with the inverse I get just the letters NT...

Comment: The coordinates are in (x,y) format. You have the basic idea, but the matchstick tips come in later.

Comment: @jafe (red, blue) is E. And I suspect there is another typo in the dark blue row. 
My guess with 9 unique letters (E, F, H, I, L, N, O, S, T) in a 9x9 grid, is that is might be a sudoku puzzle. (which is why I suspect that there is an error with the double I's in the dark blue row.) Edit: Yellow-Darkblue is Yellow-Blue. That I should be 1 row lower

Comment: Added an explanation for the final step.

Comment: The bounty notice will disappear once I award the bounty, so I'll copy it here: "Awarding jafe a bounty not for this answer (though it's good) but for his stupendous https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/105330/93 (because it's impossible to bounty a question)."

Comment: @msh210 lol, I was wondering why I randomly got 5 upvotes on this question 2 years later. Why this answer specifically?